# Odd Light Defects on Material

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

I am brand new to Blender (2.93) and I was exporting my first render and I noticed these weird light defects on my wood material, but could not pinpoint a cause. [image: Image 1]

(Look at the area on the floor to the left of the light ray)

[image: Image 2]

(Frame right after the previous image, notice that the defects changed)

[The Blend file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dzs6ebw4dpb4t4g/ChairInRoom.blend?dl=0)

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: @vklidu but why does it only do that in specific parts of the scene?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess pixel differences comes from several facts

- animation (movement changes)
- Cycles with quite low samples and most of that
- Denoising ...

Dark place with low samples generates more noise (more than in other places like completely black or lighted areas). Too much noisy area that runs trough denoiser will produce more visible distortion in reconstruction.

BTW that is not only one place in your image that differs (it is just more visible).
When you mix these two images with difference type you can see that more pixels are not matching (when it matchs it would be completely black).

[image]
[image]

If you disable Denoiser you would see what denoiser is dealing with :) You can also test it ... do a Border render of that area with 2000 Samples (without denoiser) and check the result (do not save as JPEG).

If that wouldn't be satisfying you play with Light Paths > Clamping setting under Render Properties.

Comment: Thanks! I noticed that dark wood boards had more defects. Also, how did you get this view and what clamping settings would you recommend?

Comment: You can use any image editor that supports mixing image layers - second layer is mixed with first layer by Difference type. YOu can use blender's Compositor or Photoshop, Krita or what ever it is basic operation, just in this case (as I wrote) there is many pixel because of camera movement, jpg compression, denoiser so it is a bit useless. About Clamping - by default there is already value that should work in most cases to eliminate strong white pixels ... so you have to experiment. But main issue in your case is low samples and denoiser together, not clamp.